# How to - Hidden transition on nth-child

Tags: html, css, transition

I aplied transition to "ul > li > a" and I would like to turn off transition for last child (4th). Simply speaking i dont want "contact" to be affected by the transition

Any ideas ? I tried to trigger transition to a class but it doesn't work.

Cheers

**HTML**

```
<header id="header" class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Company</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a class="button-menu" href="#header">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="button-menu" href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a class="button-menu" href="#business">Our Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="button-menu contact-border" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-header > ul > li > a {
    position: relative;
}

.main-header > ul > li > a:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 25%;
      background-color: #868686;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

.main-header > ul > li > a:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }

.main-header > ul > li:nth-child(4) {
  transition: none; <--???
}
```

Comment: The transition only affects the way changes are applied to the element, not those changes themselves. Also, you have the transition on a different element than where you put `transititon: none;`.

Comment: `.main-header > ul > li:last-child a:hover::before {
  transition: none;
}` would be what you wanted to try.

Comment: I don't want the underline transition to be affecting 4th-child at all

Comment: you mean you don't want undernline on the last one ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes

Comment: Next time, ask more precisely please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `not()` selector to remove the `nth-child(4)` from the `hover` state:

```css
.main-header>ul>li>a {
  position: relative;
  text-decoration:none;
}

.main-header>ul>li>a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
  background-color: #868686;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

.main-header>ul>li:not(:nth-child(4))>a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="main-header">
  <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Company</a></h1>
  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a class="button-menu" href="#header">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-menu" href="#products">Products</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-menu" href="#business">Our Business</a></li>
    <li><a class="button-menu contact-border" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Comment: It's good practice to separate connecting parts (`+`, `~`, `>`) of selectors using a space. Aside from the fact that having a selector like `.main-header>ul>li:not(:nth-child(4))>a:hover:before` in your code clearly shows you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
.main-header > ul > li:nth-child(4) { transition: none; }
```

**To:**

```
.main-header > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a:before { content: none; }
```

```css
.main-header > ul > li > a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.main-header > ul > li > a:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 50%;
      height: 1px;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 25%;
      background-color: #868686;
      visibility: hidden;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
      transform: scaleX(0);
      -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }

.main-header > ul > li > a:hover:before {
      visibility: visible;
      -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
      transform: scaleX(1);
    }

.main-header > ul > li:nth-child(4) > a:before {
  content: none;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="main-header">
    <h1 class="name"><a href="#">Company</a></h1>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a class="button-menu" href="#header">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a class="button-menu" href="#products">Products</a></li>
        <li><a class="button-menu" href="#business">Our Business</a></li>
        <li><a class="button-menu contact-border" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
```